# How is the anglicism "jackpot" commonly expressed in French?

Tags: anglicismes

We were having a conversation at a casino about a jackpot pool carried over, and I said:

> Ça va sûrement te paraître évident, mais plus **le jackpot** est important, plus il y a de gens qui essaieront de le remporter. Donc, si tu restes là à attendre que la cagnotte s'élève, un gars viendra tenter sa chance et te soufflera **le pactole** sous le nez. Je ne voudrais pas être celui qui en fait l’amère expérience.

To express the idea of "*a jackpot*" in English, here I said "*le jackpot*" and "*le pactole*" for no other reason than these two just happened to be the first phrases that sprang to mind in the flow of conversation.

But I'm not sure how this idea (of "*a jackpot*") is commonly/idiomatically expressed in French, as several phrases come to mind.

Answer (score 5):

Certains te diront qu'employer « jackpot » en français est un anglicisme. Certes... mais le mot se trouve dans la plupart des dictionnaires français,  le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*, le *Petit Robert*, entre autres. [Le wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jackpot) donne un exemple tiré d'un grand hebdomadaire français dont la qualité de la langue est réputée.

> *Autre grande gagnante de ce **jackpot** électoral : La France Insoumise. Elle va percevoir, pour la première fraction, plus de 3,5 millions d’euros*. — (Un grand coût dans les partis, *Le Canard enchaîné*, 14 juin 2017, page 2)

Pour les puristes qui n'ont pas tout perdu il reste « le gros lot » :

> un gars viendra tenter sa chance et te soufflera le gros lot sous le nez.

Dans le domaine des jeux, en particulier c'est depuis longtemps que jackpot est essentiellement utilisé à la place de gros lot.

> Un Haut-Garonnais a gagné le jackpot en jouant à l’Euromillions ce mardi 28 mai. ([*L'Indépendant*](https://www.lindependant.fr/2019/05/30/haute-garonne-il-gagne-32-millions-deuros-a-leuromillions,8229734.php))

Mais tu ne voudras pas employer « jackpot » deux fois dans ta phrase, donc tu peux dire « jackpot » la première fois et « gros lot » la deuxième. Je n'emploierais pas « pactole », même si ça se comprend très bien, ça fait un peu désuet.

Il existe aussi le « magot ». Mais ça fait plus penser à de l'argent qu'on cache (parce qu'il a été volé par exemple) qu'à de l'argent gagné au jeu.

Et il y a aussi « la cagnotte » qu'on peut utiliser dans le vocabulaire du jeu mais pas seulement. Moi je ne l'emploierais pas et je trouve que ça n'irait pas bien dans ton exemple, ou alors à la limite avec cagnotte la première fois et jackpot ou gros lot la deuxième.

Comment: I see. In my first phrase, though, doesn't "*plus le **gros** lot est **important***" sound odd? Perhaps, is it better to say "*plus le **gros** lot est **élevé***" ?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens À mon avis les deux conviennent.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Regarding your concern about using "gros lot" in your first phrase as is, since "lot" by itself can mean ["C. − Ce que reçoit le gagnant d'une loterie"](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lot), maybe you could add a tiny tinge of tongue-twisting tomfoolery by trimming it down to "mais plus le lot est gros ..." (or even further to "mais plus gros le lot").

Comment: +1 for the usage, as even if Iam french, I had to search what pactole mean, never heard someone that used that word in a day to day talk.

Comment: 'cagnotte' peut aussi  marcher.

Comment: @yagmoth555 "Toucher le pactole" is quite common though, I use and hear it here and there but there's simply not many occasions to use it.

Comment: C'est un mot dont j'ai déjà été très content de l'existence au Scrabble en tout cas...

Comment: @LaurentS. C'est une question de génération,  yagmoth555 doit être beaucoup plus jeune que toi et encore plus que moi. Comme je disais, ça fait désuet, je n'ai pas l'impression que les jeunes l'emploient. FL remplit son objectif si certains apprennent des mots nouveaux !